# How to translate these kind of phrases?

Tags: adjectives, translation

I am confused in translating some kind of phrases such as these.

Which one of the pairs is true? If both, What is the difference? and what is the meaning of the phrase? (I mean if I want to explain the phrase what I must say?)

- Security function requirement interfering actions
- Security function requirement interfered actions
- Security function requirement enforcing actions
- Security function requirement enforced actions

Update :
I want to translate the following paragraph in Persian. But I don't understant the **...ing** words in the bold phrases return to which one of the words in back!

Note : SFR = Sequrity Function Requirement

> The purpose of this work unit is to supplement the details about the
>   **SFR-enforcing actions** (provided in work unit ADV_FSP.3-6) with a
>   summary of the remaining actions (i.e., **those that are not
>   SFR-enforcing**). This covers all **SFR-supporting** and **SFR-non-interfering**
>   actions, whether invokable through **SFR-enforcing TSFI** or through
>   **SFR-supporting** or **SFR-non-interfering** TSFI. Such a summary about all
>   **SFR-supporting** and **SFR-non-interfering actions** helps to provide a more
>   complete picture of the functions provided by the TSF, and is to be
>   used by the evaluator in determining whether an action or TSFI may
>   have been mis-categorised.

Comment: Inappropriate elision causes ambiguities like this. Include every word and see what the sentence implies. HTH.

Comment: @Kris Question Updated. please take a look. Thanks

Comment: One way to understand the (possible/ intended) meanings relate to the direction: "SFR **interfered** actions" are actions that **are interfered with** by SFR; "SFR **interfering** actions" are actions that **interfere with** SFR.

Comment: So the meaning of **Those that are not SFR-enforcing** is : Those actions that are not enforces SFRs, Right?

Comment: Please check again -- " that are not enforces SFRs, " needs correction. However, "not SFR-enforcing" is fine.

Comment: @Kris That are not enforce SFRs! right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -ing form in the examples could be replaced by a relative sentence:

action SFR-enforcing       = action that enforces SFR

action not SFR-enforcing   = action that does not enforce SFR

action SFR-supporting      = action that supports SFR

action not SFR-supporting  = action that does not support SFR

action SFR-interfering     = action that interferes with SFR

action not SFR-interfering = action that does not interfere with SFR

At first sight, the past participle form, ending in -ed, is not correct.